# How to choose a topic for astronomy internship?

Tags: education

I am an undergraduate student who has taken up modules in Astrophysical fluids and basic astrophysics. Yet I am not able to decide how to choose a super specific topic for my research internship. Can you please suggest some ways?

Comment: You'll need to discuss this with your teachers and others who know you well academically. As we don't know you well, we won't be able to give a useful answer, and in fact we would only be giving ill-informed opinions, which won't help and could be a bad thing.

Comment: @JamesK Exactly.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* You may find this interesting/helpful! [Basic, learning examples of applications of CFD and MHD in astrophysics, and current research directions using these techniques?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44194/7982) And if you can rewrite your question to be more specific like this and more easily addressed with fact-based answers rather than opinions, it might be possible to reopen your question here as well.