# How to locate helpful and instructive books and resources about numerical methods in cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, n-body-simulations, resource-request

I am interested in the hydrodynamical and N-body simulations, and I want to use simulation results to examine the theoretical models.

Hence I am searching for some helpful and instructive books and lectures for learning relevant numerical methods, such as:

- cloud-in-cell interpolation scheme
- the process of calculating the power spectrum
- data visualization

and similar. How might I best find resources like these?

Comment: potentially helpful: [Basic, learning examples of applications of CFD and MHD in astrophysics, and current research directions using these techniques?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44194).

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for your help!

Comment: For n-body simulation, you'll need some differential equations knowledge.  I can't recommend the Udacity "Differential equations in action" enough.  One of the first assignments is a gravitational slingshot.  And several n-body problems further in. https://www.classcentral.com/course/udacity-differential-equations-in-action-456

Answer (score 3):

I found these two resources very helpful:
Lecture notes on Cosmological Simulations by Oliver Hahn

https://www-n.oca.eu/ohahn/teaching/cosmological_simulations.pdf

A more summarized form :

[https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/~komatsu/lecturenotes/Linda_Blot_on_NumericalMethods.pdf](https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/%7Ekomatsu/lecturenotes/Linda_Blot_on_NumericalMethods.pdf)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Exchange, please elaborate on your answer by citing text from the website.

Comment: @fasterthanlight consider that this is a *resource-request question* and that these two documents are long (50 & 27 pages) and quite dense. Is it really practical to try to find some small bit of each one to quote here that could at all improve the answer? I think in this particular case the answer is fine as-is.